# Object inside a callback

Tags: node.js

I am using nodejs sockets and I am trying this (relevant parts only):

```
// SOCKETS callbacks
let myServerSocketEnd = () =>
{
    if (s.isCclient)
    {
        console.log(s.name+' DISCONNECTED');
    }
}
// SERVER callbacks
let myServerCreate = (socket) => {
    let s = new clientNode(socket);

    socket.setEncoding('utf8');

    socket.on('end', myServerSocketEnd);
};
// SERVER instance
const server = net.createServer(myServerCreate);
```

So, when a new connection takes place, it creates a new object from clientNode class for custom processing by socket.on() calls, later on.

Since I have defined socket.on() using Arrow Function, how can I use the **s** object there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think there's enough code.  Where does `s` come from?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat `s` is a local inside `myServerCreate `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another closure as the argument for the `socket.on` callback which captures `s` and passes it along to your original callback:

```
// SOCKETS callbacks
let myServerSocketEnd = ( s ) =>
{
    if (s.isCclient)
    {
        console.log(s.name+' DISCONNECTED');
    }
}

// SERVER callbacks
let myServerCreate = (socket) => {
    let s = new clientNode(socket);

    socket.setEncoding('utf8');

    socket.on('end', () => myServerSocketEnd( s ) ); // <-- here
};

// SERVER instance
const server = net.createServer( myServerCreate );
```

Note that you can also use `this`:

> https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_passing_arguments_and_this_to_listeners
>
> The eventEmitter.emit() method allows an arbitrary set of arguments to be passed to the listener functions. Keep in mind that when an ordinary listener function is called, the standard `this` keyword is intentionally set to reference the `EventEmitter` instance to which the listener is attached.

So inside `onServerSocketEnd` the `this` reference is to the `Socket`. If each `Socket` has only one `clientNode` instance, then you can do this - if you don't mind using ad-hoc properties on `Socket`:

(This code uses named functions rather than storing anonymous functions in variables, this is largely a matter of style, not semantics):

```
function myServerSocketEnd() {

    // `this` will be the Socket instance.
    if( this.clientNode.isCclient ) {
        console.log(s.name+' DISCONNECTED');
    }
}

function myServerCreate( socket ) {

    socket.clientNode = new clientNode( socket );
    socket.setEncoding( 'utf8' );
    socket.on( 'end', myServerSocketEnd );
};


const server = net.createServer( myServerCreate );
```

That said, adding properties to standard-library types is generally a bad idea :)

Comment: Thanks!! I indeed will not add properties to socket. Agree it is not a good practice here.
The former approach using closure looks good and matches a later solution I was trying after posting here.
It seems I was on the same page ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [currying](https://javascript.info/currying-partials), where you call a function that returns a function:

```js
// API proxy
const net = {
  createServer: cb => {
    cb({
      setEncoding: () => {},
      on: (eventName, cb) => setTimeout(() => cb(), 500)
    });
  }
}

let counter = 0;

class clientNode {
  constructor(socket) {
    this.index = counter++;
    this.socket = socket;
    this.isCclient = true;
    this.name = `test${this.index}`;
  }
}
// API proxy end

let myServerSocketEnd = (s) => () =>
{
    if (s.isCclient)
    {
        console.log(`${s.name} DISCONNECTED`);
    }
}

// SERVER callbacks
let myServerCreate = (socket) => {
    let s = new clientNode(socket);
    socket.setEncoding('utf8');
    socket.on('end', myServerSocketEnd(s));
};

// SERVER instance
const server = net.createServer(myServerCreate);
const server2 = net.createServer(myServerCreate);
const server3 = net.createServer(myServerCreate);
const server4 = net.createServer(myServerCreate);
```

```js
let myServerSocketEnd = (s) => () =>
{
    if (s.isCclient)
    {
        console.log(`${s.name} DISCONNECTED`);
    }
}

// SERVER callbacks
let myServerCreate = (socket) => {
    let s = new clientNode(socket);
    socket.setEncoding('utf8');
    socket.on('end', myServerSocketEnd(s));
};

// SERVER instance
const server = net.createServer(myServerCreate);
```

Comment: Not sure this would work, since the event 'end' in socket.on() does not pass any argument to the callback. I will give it a try later on.
Many thanks!

Comment: `myServerSocketEnd` takes the `clientNode` as a parameter and returns a function that has the parameter value you used to create the function in it's scope.  So each time you call it, you get a different function back that has the value you used to create the function associated with it.  I edited the snippet to show it being called multiple times.